# objc : Identify previsou view (tabBar or pushBack)

Tags: objective-c

I have a probleme to identify previous view.

Expected : 
When you click on the tab bar item, my view load data on the webService and show it.
If you click on a data, a push view show the detail. But on the push back the view must not be reload. 
If you click on an other tab bar item and come back to the view. The view need to reload data.

My Probleme : Identify the previsous view, if it's from the push back or the tab bar item.

Is someone has an idea?

Thanks you

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSInteger index = 0;
  for (UIViewController *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
      if([view.nibName isEqualToString:@"YourViewController"])//put any `XIB name` where u want to navigate 
      break;
   index = index + 1;
  }
  //[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];

    [[self navigationController] popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
```

Comment: this is to push the detail view. My probleme is in the main view to differentiate the arrive from the push back, and the arrive from a click on a tab bar item